# The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset

Tags: 2010, reporting-services, reports

I have set up SSRS in integrated mode but am having trouble with getting it up and running.

When I try to run `report builder model`, `report builder report` or `report data source` in the report library I get a

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

I then go to the report server and try to access a report in the web service URL and I get the following message

> The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset. The
>   shared data source 'DataSourceXML' for the report server or SharePoint
>   site is not valid. Browse to the server or site and select a shared
>   data source. (rsInvalidDataSourceReference)

any ideas? this is SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues

Regarding `The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.`

**Reason :**

> The Reporting Services Web service is not configured to use Windows
>   integrated authentication.

check the same issue at [Reporting Services SharePoint Integration Troubleshooting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384252(v=sql.100).aspx)

Regarding `The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset`

When reports and data sources are created in SSRS, they are assigned unique identifiers in the ReportServer database.

When reports are uploaded, they do not recognize an existing data source with the same name the report was built with.

So perform the following steps that should solve your issue:

- Use IE, this will not work correctly in Chrome
- Go to your report server
- Click on the yellow arrow towards the right of your report name
- Click on 'Manage'
- Click on 'DataSources'
- Provide the correct Credentials/data source settings are pointing to the right places.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895070/how-get-reports-to-see-shared-data-sources)

Comment: There is no Configure Reporting Services Integration in Application Management

Comment: Sorry at manage application services, also try to check the same issue here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384252(v=sql.100).aspx search about 401 authentication issue